# What is the correct way to allocate this nested structures?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, structure

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to allocate and free the memory for this structures.

I need to use this to create FiniteTable's to use in Newton Interpolation.

```
typedef struct{
  unsigned int empty;
  float value;
}FiniteTableValue;
```

The fist one is kind of a Node that has the real value.

```
typedef struct{
  FiniteTableValue *column;
  unsigned int length;
}FiniteTableRow;
```

FiniteTableRow keeps an array of FiniteTableValues.

```
typedef struct{
  FiniteTableRow *row;
  unsigned int length;
}FiniteTable;
```

FiniteTable then keeps an array of FiniteTableRows.

```
typedef struct{
  FiniteTable *tables;
  unsigned int length;
}FiniteTableList;
```

FiniteTableList is the list of FiniteTable's

I tried to debugg it with valgrind and it seems I always access some address that I didn't allocate.

Also, is this the right way to deallocate all ?

```
FiniteTableList *ftl ...
  ...
  for(int i = 0; i < ftl->length; i++){
    FiniteTable table = ftl->tables[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < table.length; j++){
      FiniteTableRow row = table.row[j];
      free(row.column);
    }
    free(table.row);
  }
  free(ftl->tables);
  free(ftl);
```

Comment: What are the valgrind errors? Try running with `--track-origins=yes` if they involve undefined data.

Comment: It for "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) " I kind of know where they are, but all I need to know is how simply initiate all these structures with malloc

Comment: In this case, `--track-origins=yes` should point you to the source code location you need to fix. If not, you need to post the valgrind errors and the corresponding source code.

Comment: @TomKarzes Oh right typo here. On the code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your deallocation example the `Ftl` object is a `FiniteTableList` rather than a pointer (`FiniteTableList  *`). I think you meant to write:

```
FiniteTableList ftl ...
```

To allocate memory for a `FiniteTableList` structure you'd do something like this:

```
/* Assuming every table in the list will have num_rows rows and num_columns columns.  */
FiniteTableList *
allocate_table_list (int num_rows, num_columns, int num_tables)
{
  FiniteTableList * res = malloc (sizeof *res);
  res->tables = malloc (num_tables * sizeof (*res->tables));
  res->length = num_tables;
  for (int t = 0; t < num_tables; t++)
    {
      FiniteTable table = res->tables[t];
      table.row = malloc (num_rows * sizeof (*table.row));
      table.length = num_rows;
      for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)
        {
          FiniteTableRow row = table.row[r];
          row.column = malloc (num_columns * sizeof (*row.column));
          row.length = num_columns;
        }
    }
  return res;
}
```

If you want to zero-initialise the memory you allocate you can substitute the calls to `malloc` by `calloc`

Comment: What are you allocating when you do FiniteTableList  * res = malloc(sizeof *res); ?

Comment: You are allocating memory for the top-level FiniteTableList object. The (sizeof *res) expression means "the size of the the type that the pointer res points to"